# BUG: Data Extension columns are mismatched with data

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

The data in my data extension is landing within the right columns, however, it looks as though some columns "push" the data for other columns further out. Visually, the data does not match the columns the more i scroll to the right of the data extension.

Below is an example of what I'm talking about. If you look under "Category" column the values of True are out of place. Same with the "my tracking" values.

[image: Data Extension mismatch values]

I believe the issue is that there are trailing white spaces within the values under "EmailSubject" column, but I can't use the SQL TRIM() function.

Does anyone have a fix for this bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug is just with the displaying in the UI. It does not affect your actual data.

There is no way for you to 'fix this' as it is within the UI, not something that the end user has access to. You could check in the ['Known Issues' section](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?tag=Marketing%20Cloud%20Email%20Studio) or post something in the ['ideas' section](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) in Trailblazer/Success Community about it.

I would recommend downloading the file and review in excel, check it in ContactBuilder or create your own Cloudpage or other landing page (via API) to display the DE data.

Comment: Hmm I was hoping that wasn't the answer - I posted in the 'ideas' section per your recommendation.

Do you have a link to where i could learn how to display the data on a landing page? That sounds pretty useful